# .NET MVC Razor client-side validation not waiting until form submit

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I've implemented a .NET MVC form in Razor which uses client-side validation (`jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`).  My form has a number of different fields that are required and whose format is validated.  I'm using data annotations in the model to define this.  Eg:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "SSN is required")]
[RegularExpression(@"^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}|\d{9}$", ErrorMessage = "SSN must be in the format 000-00-0000")]
[Display(Name = "SSN")]
public string Ssn { get; set; }
```

It appears that the default behavior is to validate each form field **when it changes**.  Using the SSN example, as soon as I start typing an SSN, I see an error message saying "SSN must be in the format 000-00-0000".  I find this is an invasive/distracting UX since, really, no error has occurred yet; I simply haven't finished entering data.

Is there a way to configure client-side validation to not validate until at least a field has lost focus?  Ideally, not until the form has been submitted.

Thanks in advance.

**FWIW, here is what my form looks like:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AccountSetup", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { role = "form", autocomplete = "off" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Please correct the error(s) below.")
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SocialSecurityNumber, new { @class = "label-required" })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SocialSecurityNumber, new { @class = "form-control", maxlength = 11, data_mask = "000-00-0000" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SocialSecurityNumber)
    </div>
}
```

My web.config has these appsettings:

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

Comment: Need more code than this. Can't tell what is causing it to run on change.  Should be a simple fix though.

Comment: *"Is there a way to configure client-side validation to not validate until at least a field has lost focus?"* ~ That's called "Lazy" validation and that's exactly how it should already be working by default.  Have you changed any of the default validation settings?

Comment: @Mark: Updated.  Let me know what else you'd like to see.

Comment: @Sparky not that I know of. Where could I look?

Comment: The `.validate()` method contains the options and is automatically constructed by the `unobtrusive-validation` plugin.  I am not an ASP expert, so refer to the docs for the `unobtrusive-validation` plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Sparky's suggestion to look at jQuery validation documentation I found the solution.  I added the following javascript to make the form validation behave how I want it to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    disableResponsiveValidation();

    $("#register-form").on('submit', function () {
        enableResponsiveValidation();
    });

    function disableResponsiveValidation() {
        var validator = $("#register-form").data("validator");
        if (validator) {
            validator.settings.onkeyup = false;
            validator.settings.onfocusout = false;
        }
    }

    function enableResponsiveValidation() {
        var validator = $("#register-form").data("validator");
        if (validator) {
            validator.settings.onkeyup = function (element) {
                $(element).valid();
            };
            validator.settings.onfocusout = function (element) {
                $(element).valid();
            };
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want validation until submit, then just don't even bother with client-side validation. The whole point is to give the user notice as soon as possible about errors. If you just turn it off, then on submit, the form will just reload with errors from server-side validation.

Comment: Having to wait for the whole page to load just to validate the form is also not an ideal UX IMO. Doing client side validation on submit definitely isn't the same as doing it on the server.

Comment: Well, that's debatable. Validating on the server and then returning the form again on error is a practice as old as the web itself. The server is infinitely more capable of validating user input and is foolproof, whereas JavaScript can be disabled or tampered with. Also, client-side validation requires duplication of logic, which provides a vector for mistakes. And and unless your page is incredibly inefficient, bloated, and resources aren't being cached, it will be almost instantaneous on practically everything but dialup.

Comment: That's not to say you shouldn't use client-side validation, but if you do, then do it all the way and give the user instant feedback. That's my point.

Comment: We'll just have to agree to disagree.  Suggesting practices because they're "as old as the web itself" is an awful argument IMO.  That's why new, better, faster technologies come out (eg. Angular).  "Instantly" giving feedback in this case is telling someone that they've entered an invalid SSN when they've only entered the first letter.

Comment: Just because there's something new, doesn't mean you throw out the old. Follow that path, and you'll get bit every time.